# How to change the jar file path for already running JVM through Python

Tags: python, jvm, jpype

Hi all I have created a code to test the dB connection.
I am currently using Jpype package to start the JVM.
This is my code,

```
Jar = driverpath+’cuz.jar’
Jvm = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
Jpype.startJVM(Jvm,’-ea’,’-Djava.class.path=‘+Jar)
```

driverpath is been given by the user.

My Problem:
If the path provided by user is wrong then JVM is started without jar files.
Now in this case I want to change the jar file path alone for the running JVM.

Comment: What do you mean with “wrong”? The file doesn’t exist? Why don’t you check that beforehand?

Comment: I mean wrong when user gives a path where the jar file doesn’t exists... Jar file path is up to the user, he can place the jar file to his/her convinence and just have to give the path during the program run

Comment: Well, yes, the file path can be user supplied, but still, it has to exist by the time you’re invoking `startJVM`. So why don’t you test it right before that, instead of afterwards?

Comment: Thanks a lot Holger hope it works